# AudioKit AKSequencer & AKMIDISampler timing is inaccurate, stutters, and skips

Tags: swift, audio, swift4, audiokit

I'm trying to program a drum machine with mechanical metronome accuracy. Ideally it will be able to play 16th (or better yet 32nd) notes at any reasonable tempo (below 180 BPM).

AudioKit seems like a really nice library for stuff like this, however I'm unable to get it to play a wav sample with any sort of adequate timing. The below code frequently plays beats just slightly late, giving the hihat sample an unwanted swing feel, and sometimes stutters or skips. The drum machine has to have rock solid musical timing.

I get the same behavior on two separate iPhones (an iPhone 5 and an iPhone 6), an iPad 2, as well as any of the simulator devices.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way to improve the accuracy of AKSequencer timing?

```
import AudioKit

class DrumMachine {

    var sequencer = AKSequencer()
    let sequenceLength = AKDuration(beats: 8.0)

    let midi = AKMIDI()
    let drums = AKMIDISampler()

    init() {

        do {
            let hiHatFile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Hat_F#1.wav", baseDir: .resources)
            try drums.loadAudioFiles([hiHatFile])
        } catch {
            AKLog("Files or Player Didn't Load")
        }

        drums.enableMIDI(midi.client, name: "MIDI Sampler")

        sequencer.setLength(AKDuration(beats: 8))

        _ = sequencer.newTrack()
        sequencer.tracks[0].setMIDIOutput(drums.midiIn)

        let stepSize = Float(0.25) // 16th notes
        let numberOfSteps = Int(Float(sequenceLength.beats) / stepSize)
        let duration = Double(stepSize)

        for i in 0 ..< numberOfSteps {
            let step = Double(i) * stepSize

            sequencer.tracks[0].add(
                noteNumber: 42 - 12,
                velocity: 100,
                position: AKDuration(beats: step),
                duration: AKDuration(beats: duration)
            )
        }

        AudioKit.output = drums
        AudioKit.start()

        sequencer.enableLooping()
        sequencer.setTempo(100) // 100 BPM
        sequencer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the jangly timing mostly in the first couple of beats or does it persist? Do you need to have the MIDI functionality? If not, perhaps you can check out MetronomeSampleSynch example project:  https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/Examples/iOS/MetronomeSamplerSync/MetronomeSamplerSync/ViewController.swift

Comment: The timing stutter is most obvious in the first few seconds, however I can hear a subtle shuffle/swing intermittently afterwords. I don't need MIDI functionality as long as I can sequence & configure different rhythmic combinations of kick, snare, and hi hat samples. The metronome example looks promising. I'll give it a shot when I can get some time to dig in. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you you find out the solution?